# Can I scrobble Google Music on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, last.fm

Is there an app for iPhone iOS8 which will scrobble Google Music onto Last.fm?

I came across [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23730/how-to-scrobble-google-music-to-last-fm), but it only applies to Android.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a way to Scrobble from the official Google Play Music app. It's still a work in progress and it requires a Jailbroken iPhone, but it works!

https://github.com/octalmage/LastGoogle